# How to view the functionality of concatenate in Keras?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, concatenation, tensor

I was looking at the keras merge layers (https://keras.io/layers/merge/), and wanted to see what each of the layer operations perform. I imagine that their functionality is rather intuitive, but I want to figure out how to view the output for a given example.

To illustrate what I mean, I have two arrays with random input of shape (1,10) and want to see what the output would be if I were to concatenate the two arrays. However, when I do the following, I get the following error: `Layer concatenate_18 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>...All inputs to the layer should be tensors.`

```
from keras.layers import concatenate
data1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size = (1, 10))
data2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size = (1, 10))
concatenation = concatenate([data1, data2])
print(concatenation) # I want to print the output of concatenating data1 and data2
```

Based off the message, I am assuming this error has to do with the fact that the inputs are numpy arrays but I am unsure what the appropriate format should be instead? How can I view the output of using concatenate on an example? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the I figured out how to do this. I'm using different data than what I describe above, but should achieve the same behavior. Looks like I needed to specify input tensors, instantiate a model, and call predict on the data.

```
input1 = Input(shape=(3,))
input2 = Input(shape=(3,))
merge = concatenate([input1, input2])
model = Model([input1, input2], merge)

a = np.array([[1,1,1]])
b = np.array([[1,1,1]])
model.predict([a,b])
```